# Updated: Best practices for managing static content in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have some questions concerning the Zend Framework. I am attempting to route all static pages through the default controller using the now default `displayAction()` method. The intention is to have the `displayAction()` process the request by looking at the `page` param, determine if the script page exists, if it does render the view otherwise throw a 404 page not found error. Additionally, a test is done to see if a method with the same name as the param exists, if so, call on that action.

Listed here is the routing configuration from the **application.ini**

```
resources.router.routes.static-pages.route = /:page
resources.router.routes.static-pages.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.static-pages.defaults.controller = index
resources.router.routes.static-pages.defaults.action = display
```

Here is the controller actions:

```
public function someAction() {
    // do something
}

public function displayAction() {  
    // extract page param, e.g. 'some'      
    $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page');

    // create zend styled action method, e.g. 'someAction'
    $page_action = $page.'Action';

    // if a method within this controller exists, call on it
    if (method_exists($this, $page_action)) {
        $this->$page_action();
    }

    // if nothing was passed in page param, set to 'home'
    if (empty($page)) {
        $page = 'home';
    }

    // if script exists, render, otherwise, throw exception.
    if (file_exists($this->view->getScriptPath(null)."/".$this->getRequest()->getControllerName()."/$page.".$this->viewSuffix)) {
        $this->render($page);
    } else {
        throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Page not found', 404);
    }
}
```

Now, here are my questions: Is there a better way of doing this? I'm relatively new to this framework, so are there best practices which apply? Is there a better way of calling on an action from within a controller? I have done A LOT of looking around through the documentation, however, quite a bit of it seems to contradict itself.

Update 1:

After having a think and a read, I've managed to simplify the solution and include a few things which were mentioned. NOTE: I use `PagesController` as my default static-content controller.

Listed here is the routing configuration from the application.ini. For calls to the home page i.e. "/", I pass "home" as the `action` param, for all other requests, the user defined / url link param is sent in `action`.

```
resources.router.routes.home.route = "/"
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.controller = "pages"
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.action = "home"
resources.router.routes.pages.route = "/:action"
resources.router.routes.pages.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.pages.defaults.controller = "pages"
```

Here is the controller actions. If user define parameter exists as an action, it will be called, else it falls to the php magic function __call.

```
public function someAction()
{
    // Do something
}

public function __call($method, $args)
{
    // extract action param, e.g. "home"
    $page = $title = $this->getRequest()->getParam('action'); 

    // test if script exists
    if (file_exists($this->view->getScriptPath(null) . "/" 
        . $this->getRequest()->getControllerName() . "/$page . " . $this->viewSuffix)) 
   {
        // pass title to layout
        $this->view->assign(compact('title'));
        // render script
        $this->render($page);
    } else {
        throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Page not found', 404);
    }
}
```

It works. So, here are my questions: Would you consider standardising on using this method to manage static content? If not, why not? How would you improve it? Also, considering this is a GET request, would it be a wise move to use Zend_Filter_input to cleanse input or is that just overkill?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems reasonable to me. However, perhaps you should take advantage of the `__call` method instead, which would allow you to more easily route your actions...

Setup your route like this:

```
resources.router.routes.static-pages.route = /:action
resources.router.routes.static-pages.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.static-pages.defaults.controller = index
```

And your controller like so:

```
public function someAction() {
    //going to URL /some will now go into this method
}

public function __call($name, $args) {
    //all URLs which don't have a matching action method will go to this one
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I'll definitely take a look into this.

Answer (score 1):

I think your on the right track however here are some other ideas.

Break up your routing per sections in your INI:
ie a blog router, a static page router a forum router etc.. (I think you are already doing this)

Use the various router classes to handle routing per section rather than sending it to a controller.

**Static:** 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.static

**All:**
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Some links that may help:

- codeutopia.net/blog/2007/11/16/routing-and-complex-urls-in-zend-framework/
- www.vayanis.com/2009/03/20/intro-to-zend-framework-routing/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, as you say, alternative non-static routing is in place for dynamic pages. I'll take a look through the documentation to see if there is anything I can use to improve upon the design.